# How to create a custom annotation processor for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I'm trying to create a custom annotation processor that generates code at compilation time (as hibernate-jpamodelgen does). I've looked in the web, and I find custom annotation processors that works with maven, but do nothing when added to the Annotation Processing > Factory Path option. How could I create a processor compatible in this way? I have not found a tutorial that works.

My idea is to, for example, annotate an entity to generate automatically a base DTO, a base mapper, etc that can be extended to use in the final code.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Already found out the problem. The tutorial I hda found out dint't specified that, in order to the compiler to be able to apply the annotation processor, there must be a META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor file that contains the qualified class name of the processor (or processors).

I created the file pointing to my processor class, generated the jar and added it to Annotation Processing > Factory Path and all worked correctly.

Just be careful to keep the order of the processors correctly (for example, hibernate model generator claims the classes, so no more generation will be made after it), and change the jar file name each time you want to replace the library (it seems eclipse keeps a cache). These two things have given me a good headache.

Thanks all